# How do I use gtk and graphics.h together in c language?

Tags: c, graphics, gtk, shapes, gtk3

How do I use gtk3 and graphics.h together in c language?
example
I press button(make button by gtk3) then program display square(make square by graphics.h).

Comment: I know, that you don't want to hear it, but _too many cooks spoil the broth_. That being said, as long as you don't know the internals (implementation details) of the two frameworks, just don't mix them together and if you know the internals, then you 'know' not to use them side by side. It's not about whether it can be done but a matter of headaches (and of course errors in the long run).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck 
￼